# What is original content and brand owner for android app

Tags: android, google-play

I have 1 application in Google play store called Myanmar TV. I was uploaded since 2013. Yesterday they remove my application and send to me this email.

REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the IP infringement and impersonation policy help article for more information.

I want to know clearly what is original content and brand owner.Please anyone can explain me. thanks so much.

This is Google email:

Hi,

Thank you for your reply. We appreciate the opportunity to review your appeal pertaining to the removal of your application from Google Play.

After a regular review, your app has been administratively suspended pending verification that you are authorized to publish on behalf of the original content or brand owner.

We were not able to validate your account's relationship to the original content or brand owner. In order for us to process your appeal, please provide documentation that the application is authorized in your reply to this notification. Please be advised we will not be able to respond or reinstate your application without the above documentation.

We appreciate your assistance and look forward to your reply.

Regards,
The Google Play Team

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal dispute with Google and/or Google's TOS.

Comment: It sounds like Google is not able to validate your identity.  I thought that this was determined by the certificate with which you sign your app.  Give this a read: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html.

Comment: You should simply ask them what documentation would be adequate to establish that the application is authorized. Then (if you can) supply it. Note that if your app is streaming third-party content for which you need a license (the name "Myanmar TV" suggests that possibility to me) then you will need to demonstrate to Google that you have permission from the third-party source(s) to use that content in your app.